# Restrict Update Statement from actually updating the records

Tags: sql, database, db2

> Is there anyway to prevent or restrict the update statement from
>   actually updating the data in the table?

I just want to see the potential selection of the records that will be modified, if update statement runs successfully.

**I don't want to convert it into a SELECT statement. I tried it, but failed.**

Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spite of this answer, I still think the best way would be to use a select, but if you want to do the update then preview the results you can view the results of a data change using [FINAL TABLE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0011133.html), then [rollback the transaction](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_commitandrollbackoftransactions.htm)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT  SomeField 
FROM    FINAL TABLE (   UPDATE YourTable
                        SET     SomeField = SomeValue
                        WHERE   SomeOtherField = SomeOtherValue)

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Ok. This answer do not give me a quick fix of the problem I'm facing right now. Rather it gives me a very good information which will definitely help me out in future. Thanks for wonderful links. 

I still would like to ask if we have some handy technique which we can use to transform an update statement to select statement?

Once again, thanks for wonderful info. :)

Comment: There is no handy technique I know of to transform an update statement to select, although I don't see this as a particularly complex manual change `UPDATE TableName SET xx WHERE yyy` --> `SELECT xx FROM TableName WHERE yyy` is surely not overwhelming?